# Ring whose every simple singular module is faithful.

Tags: ring-theory, modules

Is there any ring (not necessary commutative), other than simple ring, whose every simple singular right $R-$module is faithful?

A $R-module$ $M$ is called faithful if $ann_r(M)=0.$

Comment: I notice that you haven't accepted any answers to your questions so far (5, to date, 1 unanswered). It seems like all of the answered ones probably deserve acceptance. There is no rush, but eventually it would be a good idea to grant the acceptable answers checkmarks. This helps to further organize answered questions into "probably acceptably answered" and "possibly not quite answered yet" categories.

Comment: Thank you, I just did not know that there is such that thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All simple right $R$ modules of a semisimple ring $R$ are not singular, and in that case it would vacuously satisfy your condition.

So, for example, $F_2\times F_2$ ($F_2$ the field of two elements) satisfies the condition and is not simple.

---

If you ask for at least one faithful simple singular module to exist, then you'd need examples of [right primitive rings that aren't simple](https://ringtheory.herokuapp.com/search/results/?H=74l&L=3), which are harder to come by.  In fact, both of those examples have nonzero right socles, and so they cannot have faithful singular right modules.